# Ubuntu 14.04.1 server 64 - gui not working

Tags: ubuntu, user-interface, cloud, server

I have ubuntu 14.04.1 (64bit) server on iwStack cloud.

I have installed gui but when I try to start gui using 'startx' gui dont work and showing fatal error: 'no screens found' after 'Loading extension GLX' line. I have searched online but did not found anything that might help me.

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeVbj.jpg

Please help.

The gui I installed is minimal gnome core desktop: sudo apt-get install xorg gnome-core gnome-system-tools gnome-app-install

Thanks
Julash